# Unable to run docker containers on the mounted storage in gce vm

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We are planning to move from on-prem to gcp, but the process of designing is taking some time. We want to deploy our docker containers on gce vms. We don't want to manually increase the storage every time the containers fill up the space, we know that this can be done by auto scaling but we don't have enough expertise on this. So, we found out that GCS can be mounted on the VM and we can run our containers on the mounted path, but when we tried touching files or running containers we are getting permission denied error. can anyone help us to resolve it we tried many docs and tutorials but they are a little bit confusing.

We used gcsfuse for mounting the bucket to the gce vm

Comment: Moving apps from onprem to cloud normally is an activity that's not so easy to carryout in a forum. Anyway, can you share at-least the docker file or docker-compose you have?

Comment: Are you working with this module: https://github.com/craimbert/docker-volume-gc-storage ?  If so, did you configure and assign the service account as described. And, does the service account have the rights to write to the bucket?

Comment: @FabioB. we were using a different module called gcsfuse. However I have tried the link which you have given and it also works for us. Thanks again for helping us solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our case we were using gcsfuse and mounted the bucket to the gce instance at /root/bucketmount. since the bucket is mounted on root fs, I have to use escalate privilege tag but it's not suggested to use. so we now changed the permissions to the folder using chown command. This helped us so In our pipeline we have created 3 steps

1 for creating a gcs bucket and mount it to the vm
2 for checking permissions for the mounted path and updating the permissions
3 for deploying the docker containers.

As of now the path is hardcoded I want to make it randomised verifing options will let you know if I succeed..

**Update**

I have created a script which will get triggered by n8n webhook and creates a random name for the mount directory and by using the same script the name of the directory will be updated to a csv file from which my CICD will fetch the details and deploy the containers.